# not possible to reshape

Tags: numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Hello when I run following code:

```
for record in training_data_list:
        all_values = record.split(',')
        y_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[0]))

        ab = np.zeros(10)
        ab[int(all_values[0])] = 1

        print("ab= " + str(ab))
        print("shape ab= " + str(ab.shape))
        ac = np.expand_dims(ab, axis=0).T
        print("ac = " + str(ac))
        print("shape AC = " + str(ac.shape))
        ac = ac.reshape((10,Y.shape[1]))
        print("shape ac = " + str(ac.shape))
```

I run into following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (10,103)
```

The shape of ac before the reshape command is (10,1)
The shape of Y = (1,103)

So I want to have as shape for ac (10,103)

Second question, why is the error telling me cannot reshape array of size 10 while the size is (10,1)?

Comment: The `shape` may be (10,1), but the `size` is 10 - 10 elements.  `reshape` can only change the `shape`, without changing the `size`.  The `size` of (10,103) is 1030!  I think you want to use `repeat`.

Comment: Hello, can you tell me how to get a shape of (10,103) then? Eventually by using the repeat command?

Comment: `np.repeat(x, 103, axis=1)`